# Use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am writing a class `float32x4_t` that mimic the ARM NEON datatype on x86 platform. There are 4 elements in its object.

I would like to `cout` an `float32x4_t` instance (print out comma separated 4 elements), but my overloaded function failed to compile.

My code is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct float32x4_t
{
    float val[4];
    float& operator [] (int i) {
        return val[i];
    }
    const float& operator [] (int i) const {
        return val[i];
    }
    int size() const {
        return 4;
    }
};


template<class T>
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const T& v)
{
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
        os << v.val[i] << ", ";
    }
    os << std::endl;
    return os;
}

/// @ingroup add
/// r[i] = a[i] + b[i]
static inline float32x4_t vaddq_f32(float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b)
{
    float32x4_t r;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        r[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    return r;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float32x4_t v1 = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
    float32x4_t v2 = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    float32x4_t sum = vaddq_f32(v1, v2);
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The whole error is like:

```
/home/zz/work/neon_pedal/neon_pedal.h:25:24: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const char [3]')
        os << v.val[i] << ", ";
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~
/home/zz/work/neon_pedal/main.cpp:18:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'operator<<<float32x4_t>' requested here
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
              ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ostream:565:5: note: candidate function [with _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
    operator<<(basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
    ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/ostream:548:5: note: candidate function [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
    operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const _CharT* __s)
    ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/ostream.tcc:321:5: note: candidate function [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
    operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __out, const char* __s)
    ^
/home/zz/work/neon_pedal/neon_pedal.h:22:16: note: candidate function [with T = char [3]]
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const T& v)
```

How can I resolve this compile error?

Note: here the overloaded `operator <<` is with template, that's because there will be more than just `float32x4_t` type. There will be such as `float32x2_t`, `int8x8_t`, `int16x8_t`, etc.

Comment: Why use a template if you need it for a single type?

Comment: @Mat There will be more than one type. Such as `float32x2_t`, `int8x8_t`, `int16x8_t`, `int32x4_t`, etc.

Comment: Conceive, for a moment, how that operator will attempt to match damn near *anything* (not just your type(s)). That alone should be  a strong indicator this design needs work. Overload for your type. If you have more than one type, write more than one overload. If you have a common base for your types, write an overload for that. But a general overload-the-world is the wrong approach.

Comment: If on C++20, you can easily constrain the template to only match your own types (or any type with a `val` array if you prefer)

Comment: @WhozCraig You mentioned me that my class design is poor. I am trying to re-design with inheritance now.

Comment: @Hasturkun Oh thanks, but I only know a little about C++11...

Comment: You could also do it with templates, which will probably be better anyway unless you planning on a polymorphic design

Comment: "re-design with inheritance" That would be a mistake. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template `operator <<` is trying to provide overloads to *everything*; not just your types (and unintended matches are ambiguous as a result).

There are many ways around this, but since you're already defining your own types and the whole goal of this is to minimize the number of `operator <<` overloads you must write to match, consider a generic TxN template, write a (singular) overload for that, then alias your real types to that as a natural evolution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<class T, size_t N = 4>
struct TxN
{
    T val[N];

    TxN() = default;

    T& operator[](size_t i)
    {
        return val[i];
    }

    T const& operator[](size_t i) const
    {
        return val[i];
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return N;
    }

    // there are at least three different ways to do this operator, but
    //  this is the easiest, so I included below.
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, TxN<T,N> const& t)
    {
        os << t.val[0];
        for (size_t i=1; i<N; ++i)
            os << ',' << t.val[i];
        return os;
    }
};

// now creating TypeN shrouds is trivial.
using float32x4_t = TxN<float, 4>;
using int16x8_t = TxN<short,8>;

/// @ingroup add
/// r[i] = a[i] + b[i]
static inline float32x4_t vaddq_f32(float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b)
{
    float32x4_t r;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        r[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    return r;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float32x4_t v1 = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
    float32x4_t v2 = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    float32x4_t sum = vaddq_f32(v1, v2);
    std::cout << sum << '\n';

    int16x8_t i0 = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    std::cout << i0 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: Cool! This is simple and is what I expected to be. Btw, I just also tried using std::array, with `typedef std::array<float, 4> float32x4_t;`, which also seems works. Your answer is more straight forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to overload `<<` operator for all of the types. So if there is a type for which `<<` operator is already overloaded in std namespace, it will be ambiguous as the compiler doesn't know which one to choose, your overload or the one in std namespace.

```
 for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
    os << v.val[i] << ", ";
 }
```

Specifically, the `const char[] = ", "` is causing the issue as there's an overload for that in the std namespace already. Note that you're also calling
`os << std::endl` but you're being explicit with `std::` so there's no ambiguity. If you want to use `ostream` overloads present in `std` namespace which I'm assuming you do, then there is no way to make your templatized overload feasible. 
You can just declare a friend overload in your struct.

```
friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os,const float32x4_t & self){
         ...
}
```